# MySQL error involving backticks

Tags: mysql, database-design, backticks

I'm having some problems with this piece of mySQL code that is not wanting to get fixed

```
CREATE TABLE `DatabaseMGR`
  (
    `databaseID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `primCat` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `databaseName` VARCHAR(20),
     UNIQUE KEY (`databaseID`),
     PRIMARY KEY (`databaseID`),
     INDEX `databaseID`
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

It says that there is an error at line 1 with the regular "check your mysql syntax for right usage" error in response to ` usage. Is there something I'm missing? I'm new to sql so I might be missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want 3 indexes on the same column?Primary is enough

Comment: You need to put INDEX databaseID in ( ) as the other keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point for your problem is at the line you are defining the index. In `create table` statement, you should use it with this syntax:

```
 create table table_name (
    ...
    index `INDEX_NAME` (`INDEX_COLUMN`)
 );
```

So you can fix your problem by changing your code to below:

```
CREATE TABLE `DatabaseMGR`
  (
    `databaseID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `primCat` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `databaseName` VARCHAR(20),
     UNIQUE KEY (`databaseID`),
     PRIMARY KEY (`databaseID`),
     INDEX `ix_databaseID` (`databaseID`) # Note the change on this line
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However, in MySQL `primary key` column gets an index by default, so you can leave out that line totally, that results in the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `DatabaseMGR`
  (
    `databaseID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `primCat` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `databaseName` VARCHAR(20),
     UNIQUE KEY (`databaseID`),
     PRIMARY KEY (`databaseID`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

**To improve more:**

- `databaseID` is already a `primary key`, so you do not have to make define it `unique` again, since: `primary key` = `unique` + `not null`
- Since MySQL is case insensitive, you should not use camel case names. So instead of `databaseID`, better to say `database_id`. There are more naming convention you can go through, though I will not mention here.

So for final table defination I suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE `database_mgr`
  (
    `database_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `prim_cat` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `database_name` VARCHAR(20),
     PRIMARY KEY (`databaseID`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a different understanding of  unique key usage and index than what i really meant. Thanks for the clarification.